# Tmux 1.8 - unknown option: window-style

Tags: tmux

I am trying set the color for Tmux active and inactive window. However it seems like these options are not available in `tmux 1.8`. 
is there any alternative

**.tmux.conf**

```
set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
#-------------------------------------------------------#
# Pane colours
#-------------------------------------------------------#
# set active-inactive window styles
set -g window-style 'fg=colour247,bg=colour236'
set -g window-active-style 'fg=default,bg=colour234'

# Pane border
set -g pane-border-bg default
set -g pane-border-fg colour238

# Active pane border
set -g pane-active-border-bg default
set -g pane-active-border-fg blue
```

**Error**

```
 tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
/home/gshah03@office.adroot.bmogc.net/.tmux.conf:6: unknown option: window-style
/home/gshah03@office.adroot.bmogc.net/.tmux.conf:7: unknown option: window-active-style
```

Comment: Sorry no solution for this in the old version. But it's rather simple to compile new version of tmux. Even if you are using a machine where you don't have admin rights, you can compile it in your home folder run it from there.

Answer (score 1):

No, support for this feature was not added until tmux 2.1.